# Is it possible to wrap both for regular exception and SEH exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, swig, seh

I have a native C++ library and a SWIG-generated wrapper for C#. the `.i` file contains an `%exception` that wraps all the `$action`s inside regular `try/catch`blocks to convert exceptions to our desired target C# exceptions using `SWIG_CSharpSetPendingExceptionCustom`. Something like this

```
%exception {
    try
    {
        $action
    }
    catch(const our::Exception& exc)
    {
        //blahblah
        SWIG_CSharpSetPendingExceptionCustom(/*blah*/);
        return $null;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& exc)
    {
        /*blah*/
    }       
    catch(...)
    {
        /*blah*/
    }
}
```

This works great, all regular C++ exceptions are nicely wrapped and forwarded to C#.

But what I also need is to wrap all my function with the SEH `__try/__except` blocks in order to catch potential access violations and whatnot and print the native stack trace. Something like

```
%exception {
    __try
    {
        $action
    }   
    __except(print_my_stack_trace(GetExceptionInformation()))
    {       
    }   
}
```

Unfortunately it is not allowed to combine regular `try` with SEH `__try` in one function in any way. So if my library has an arbitrary function myclass::f, what I would like to achieve is for SWIG to first create a f_temp function whose body will contain try/catch, then the true wrapper of f that would call f_temp wrapped with `__try/__catch`. The result for f would look something like

```
void SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_blah_myclass_f_TEMP__(void * jarg1) {
  myclass *arg1 = (myclass *) 0 ;
  
  arg1 = (myclass*)jarg1; 
  {
    try
    {
      (arg1)->f();
    }
    catch(const our::Exception& exc)
    {
      ...
      SWIG_CSharpSetPendingExceptionCustom(...);
      return ;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& exc)
    {
      ...
    }
}

SWIGEXPORT void SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_blah_myclass_f__(void * jarg1) {
     __try
    {
      CSharp_blah_myclass_f_TEMP__(jarg1)
    }
    __except(print_my_stack)
    {
      
    }    
}
```

I am thinking of resorting to writing a perl script that would manipulate the swig-generated wrapper .cpp file textually, but I first want to make sure that this is not possible to achieve with swig magic. So, can anyone think of a SWIG solution that does not involve ad-hoc manipulation of generated sources?

Comment: I think you can maybe use [_set_se_translator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-se-translator?view=msvc-170#example-catch-__try-exception-error) approach to translate SEH exception into C++ one (see example with try/catch there).

Comment: Also, in my experience it is better to not try and catch SEH exception, print some info and then try to carry on. Usually it is better to let the application crash. That way you can get a crash dump that contains the full SEH exception information in a format that the debugger understands, including the context (local variables etc., if not optimized out) where the SEH exception originated.